# PHP Composer issue (Technic Solder API Setup)

Tags: php, composer-php, minecraft

I am in the process of setting up a webserver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and have got my LEMP stack setup properly, as well as installed composer without issue.

When I try to configure composer for use with the solder package via the following command:

```
$composer require solder/solder
```

it spits out the following error:

```
Using version v0.7.3.1 for solder/solder
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for solder/solder v0.7.3.1 -> satisfiable by solder/solder[v0.7.3.1].
    - solder/solder v0.7.3.1 requires composer/composer 1.0.0-alpha9 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.0.0-alpha9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

I even tried running it in sudo mode, same issue (yes, I know your not supposed to run composer commands in sudo or root level access mode, but I tried it just to rule it out as the issue)

Any idea what is causing this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The `solder/solder` package requires the `composer/composer` package explicitly in version `1.0.0-alpha9`. Composer however (ignore the confusing fact that you're using Composer to install Composer for a moment), will not install "unstable" software (i.e. `alpha`, `beta` or `dev` versions) by default.

You can circumvent this by setting the [`minimum-stability` setting](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) in your `composer.json` file. For this, create the `composer.json` file by hand:

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "solder/solder": "0.7.3.1"
    }
}
```

Followed by running `composer install` on the command-line.

In comparison, the `composer require` command that you're using does nothing else that adding the `solder/solder` key/value pair to the `composer.json`'s `require` section (also implicitly creating the file, but without the `minimum-stability` setting) and running an implicit `composer install`.